# padding numpy array/matrix with string

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to read a multi-band image in a python code. My requirement is to form a neighborhood matrix. So I need to pad the matrix with with some number so as to be able to form neighborhood for each element. 
Ex. a is a matrix, padding with 0

```
a= |1 2 3 |
   |4 5 6 |
   |7 8 9 |
neighborhood matrix = |0 0 0|
                      |0 1 2|
                      |0 4 5|
```

I am using `numpy.pad(below)` for this and it works perfectly with single band. But for multi-band, it converts noDataValue to its equivalent in 0-255 and pads with it, which I do not want.

```
pixels = np.pad(a, (padding,padding), mode='constant', constant_values=(noDataValue))
```

where `padding = 1`, `noDataValue = -999.0` but it automatically converting it to 125. And this is happening only for multiband. So any help would be appreciated.

Or

If I can pad matrix with a string, that would be great. I could not find any function that helps padding with String.

**Update 1**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert `a` to a type which can be the value noDataValue

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
# ....
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
a = np.array(a).astype(np.float32)
padding = 2
noDataValue = -999.0
pixels = np.pad(a, (padding,padding), mode='constant', constant_values=(noDataValue))
```

It works here

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'. Will it pad with any number?

Comment: Sorry, you need to convert to 2D numpy array, 2 secs. Working now?

Comment: Well I tried this,

    a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    Alpha = np.reshape(a, (-1, 3))
    Alpha = Alpha.astype(np.int64)

Error: KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: @AN_SH The above works here. You cannot reshape a list. It needs to be a Numpy array

Comment: Its working on simple array, which was already working. let me check on multiband array.

Comment: @AN_SH Remember to cast to a type, which can hold the noDataValue - otherwise it may be truncated to an int8

Comment: Great its working. But i am adding noDataValue = -999.0 and it pads with -999 only. I want it to be decimal too.

Comment: Simply convert to datatype, which can hold -999.0. `.astype(np.float)`

Comment: e.g.
    pixels: [[-999 -999 -999 ..., -999 -999 -999]
                [-999   43   40 ...,   17   18 -999]
                [-999   61   51 ...,   14   16 -999]
                 ..., 
       
               [-999   42   56 ...,   19   18 -999]
               [-999 -999 -999 ..., -999 -999 -999]]

Comment: One more thing. Since i am working on multibands, array a bands at different indexes. Like 7 band, a[0] = band 1, a[1]= band 2. Do I convert the array a to astype or taking separate arrays in new array and then convert.

Comment: @AN_SH The `astype` can work on a N-dimensional array. Does this answer you question?

Comment: I have added the original array image in the question update 1. So array_pixels = a[0] and like that. So can I use astype on array_pixels or getting a[0] first and then converting. Also please tell me why it does not work, if do not use astype with multibands. however works with single band?

Comment: By multiband I assume you are considering RGBA values. If you want to create a new valid RGBA image values has to be 0-255.

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand what you try to achieve. If you want to interpret an image and do some filtering or something the conversion makes sense. In this case you can do this for each RGBA component

Comment: Ok I understand this part. But can you please explain why it works fine for single bands without using astype and not with multi band. I have implemented same code for single bands and it works fine.

Comment: What is multiband?

Comment: Convert to an array and look at the dimensions. Probably 4x320x320. Then pick color components one at a time, e.g. `img [0,:,:]` and use the approach for single band

Comment: Dimensions could be different. Use colons and an index. You may need to call np.squeeze before using np.pad. Stitch together using np.r_ or np.c_

Comment: One more query, to keep noDatavalue = -999.0 as float, we are using float32, but this afect every value in the array. I just want keep nodatavalue as float but do not change other values. Please help.

Comment: Not possible. The pad function requires identical types, so does an image. It does not make sense to pad with strings either. Need to go to bed....